# Preprocess function for an image

Tags: 8, media, theming

I'm trying to add custom class to an image.

The image is generated with a image field called "field_hero" so i'm trying to add a class to this image that is generated from that specific field.

Right now, I've tried with :

```
function mytheme_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_hero') {
       $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'custom-class';
    }
  }   
}
```

I can actually add a class with `$variables['attributes']['class'][]`

But with the if statements it doesn't work because it doesn't go through.

How can i make it work?